# Console undefined in Chrome

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a `save` function that calls a service. I subscribe to the results of the service call by passing it a success function and an error function. The success function works as expected. However, when the error function is called because of an invalid request made to the service, I receive the following error:

```
Error from Save command: TypeError: Cannot read property 'log' of undefined
```

This is happening because for whatever reason, `console` becomes undefined in the error function. But what is weird is that `console.log` works perfectly fine in the success function.

Here is a snippet of the `save` function:

```
this.returnFileParameterService.save(this.selectedParam).subscribe(
            res => {
                let param = _.find(this.returnFileParameters, param => _.isUndefined(param.id) || _.isNull(param.id));
                if (_.isUndefined(param)){
                    param = _.find(this.returnFileParameters, ['id', res.id]);
                }
                _.set(param, 'id', res.id);
                _.set(param, 'modifiedDate', res.modifiedDate);
                console.log("test");
            },
            err => console.log('Error from Save command: ' + err)
        );
```

Comment: Does this only affect Chrome?

Comment: I'm a bit confused.  The error you receive looks like the one that is emitted from the error handler.  I don't think its `console` that's undefined.  It seems the promise is being rejected with "Cannot read property 'log' of undefined".  Can you clarify this?

Comment: Wow. You're absolutely correct. Can't believe I missed that. But still not exactly sure what is going on lol...

Comment: I'm not sure either.  Somewhere in your code you're trying to reference a `log` property on some object (of yours, not the console), but that code isn't in the question.

Comment: OK, I figured it out: I was calling `.catch(this.handleError);` to add my error handler as the catch subscriber, but inside my error handler I had this line: `this.logger.log('handleError()');`. `this.logger` didn't exist because `this` was set to the function calling the error handler instead of the class the error handler was contained in, so I needed to add a closure to the catch subscription: `.catch(error => this.handleError(error));`.

Comment: I suggest adding that as an answer to your question.  You'll be able to accept it after a time-limit has passed.  Free rep!  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I figured it out: I was calling `.catch(this.handleError);` to add my error handler as the catch subscriber, but inside my error handler I had this line: `this.logger.log('handleError()');`. `this.logger` didn't exist because `this` was set to the function calling the error handler instead of the class the error handler was contained in, so I needed to add a closure to the catch subscription: `.catch(error => this.handleError(error));`.